# Creating an App ID with xCode

Tags: ios, xcode

As I understand xCode is capable of creating an App ID on developer portal . I have created a test application with the bundle identifier "com.xxxxxExample.appname" . However nor a wildcard or explicit is created on developer portal and application runs on on the device using the team provision profile.

For education purposes I want to know whether xCode is capable of creating wildcard App IDs on the developer portal ?

If it's there a way to create it using xCode, how should I trigged it ?

On documentation it specifies as follows ,

> Xcode creates an App ID to match your bundle ID, which is a unique
>   identifier for your app stored in the app bundle. Xcode initially
>   creates a wildcard App ID and an explicit App ID only if needed

Answer (score 2):

Xcode provide to create an explicit App ID with the specific bundle id when you modify the default settings of the ***Capabilities*** of your application.

Comment: This is correct , but what about the wild card ID ? Does it always defaults to teamId ?

Comment: The wild card remain a wild card nothing change.
After the xCode have created the bundle id if you check in the member center you can configure the capabilities of your application.
For example if in the app you have enabled the Push Notification now you can configure it.